# If I just purchased a game, but canceled the download, how do I get it back?

Tags: nintendo-network-id, nintendo-switch

I just bought Snake Pass, but my internet started having a seizure, so I canceled the download. It is now gone from my homepage. When I go to the E shop, it just shows purchased. How do I re-download the game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can re-download them via the Nintendo Switch eShop.

> Check “Redownloads” in the Nintendo Switch eShop (in your account
>   information). Any games that have been purchased or redeemed on the
>   system will appear here, and can be re-downloaded at no additional
>   cost.

Follow [these steps.](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/16482)

On that page, Click **Downloading a game**, then **I don't see the game on my Nintendo Switch!**